# What is the difference between "I am always busy" and "I have always been busy"?

Tags: tense, difference, perfect-constructions

Here is the question:

> Someone says: "Anyhow, I'd never have time to watch it." 
>       Which of the following choice could be correctly added to the sentence?
>
> A) because **I was** always busy
>       B) because **I am** always busy
>       C) because **I have always been** busy
>       D) because **I will always be** busy

I feel it is either B) or C), but not sure the difference of B) and C), could someone help and explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer

> I'd never have time = **I *would* never** have time : hypothetical, *I think so*
>
> B) because **I am always** busy : present tense - generally true, *I am*

---

The difference

> B) because **I am always** busy

- It’s just the way someone is.

***You know me***, I’m always busy.

- It's out of discussion. I won't stop being busy.

***No, I am always busy***. I can't meet up with you tomorrow.

> C) because **I have always been** busy

- It stresses that it has something to do with the present.

*I have always been busy **and now** I too tired for that.*

- It could imply you stop being busy from now on.

*I have always been busy **but now** I have more time for myself.*

Comment: "I have always been busy and now I too tired for that." This verb tense construction should not be used. It should be *I* ***had*** *always been busy but now I [am]  too tired for that.* If you save *have* that means you still are. You can't  say that and then say "but not anymore." You could also say *I used to be*.

Comment: guys, could you please tell me which choice have you made? a,b,c or d?